# Getting error after migrating to Ember octane

Tags: ember.js, ember-octane

I am using Ember 3.16.3 and i am getting this error on the following code :

> Error: Assertion Failed: You must pass a function as the second
>   argument to the `on` modifier

```
//login.hbs

 <form {{on "submit" this.login}}>
       <Input type="email" placeholder="email" @value={{this.email}} />
      <button type="submit">login</button>
 </form>
```

.

```
//login.js

import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class LoginRoute extends Route {

   @tracked email = '';

   @action
   login(event) {
     event.preventDefault();

     // do some operations ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As specified in the error, the `on` modifier should receive a valid function to execute. As mentioned in the [guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.14.0/templates/actions/),

> If you add the `{{action}}` helper to any HTML DOM element, when a user clicks the element, the named event will be sent to the template's corresponding component or controller.

This holds good for `on` modifier or any values that are used in the template. You can think of routes to be a part where we fetch data for the corresponding page. Any other backing property or computation has to be defined inside a controller or component to be used in the template.

Hence, moving your `login` action to a [Controller](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.16.0/routing/controllers/) will solve this issue. Additionally, you need to move `email` to the controller as well, or you won't see updates to it work correctly.